# Keyboard pushes actionbar up / off screen, adjustResize doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

When the keyboard pops up the Actionbar gets pushed up like in the screenshot. When I resize the keyboard to be bigger the Actionbar get pushed completly off screen.

The Class extends `AppCompatActivity`, if that matters.

I am using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but it seems not to work like I think it does.

[image: Action bar pushed up]

this is my layout.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/eTUserName"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|textFilter"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxLines="1">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogIn"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/login" />
```

and this is the activity tag.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".EntryPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```